# How to trim line breaks and spaces in string using php

Tags: php

I have a string as below.

```
$key="bf3iZzS9vJFf68R2DgKcVEb0gG2ZuxB2N3nx/VmCgnvQweTiPhdGIWgoifR/a2Cj7yhD6RnAlqPD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"
```

I want the string to be like

```
$key="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"
```

I have tried the below method.

```
str_replace("\n", "", $key);
```

But it not worked.

Any suggestions..?

Thanks

Comment: Question to all: would using str_replacing `PHP_EOL` be suitable for this?

Comment: @MackieeE : dat's d 1st thing I tried, but its Not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY

```
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '';     
$final = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
var_dump($final);
```

**NOTE :** Because [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. so Processes `\r\n`'s first so they aren't converted twice.

Comment: Wouldn't `$order = array("\n", "\r");` be enough?

Comment: Actually here i am facing a different problem. I am sending that key to another server using XML. If you see the string there are '+' symbols in middle. So Before sending the request i am printing the variable(contains the string).Now the the '+' symbols are there but after sending the request in response i am getting a error(you cannot change the Key). The thing is that after sending the request the + symbols are getting removed. Do you have any idea regarding this...?

Comment: So you are sending this data via HTTP in some way. Form data is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when sent by a browser, and in that spaces are replaced by the `+` character. So if you are sending plain `+`, the receiver will most likely assume that you _meant_ spaces and will decode them accordingly. So URL-encode your data correctly before sending it via HTTP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this,I think it is a simple way

```
 echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $key);
```

Comment: Nice, but this will fix input only on the current system. If your server uses Windows and content is submitted from Mac for example, it won't replace them.

Comment: @elavarasanlee,I copy the string from the question,And checked with that string.

Comment: @shin Chiclets... Even I did d same thing... :P and as I said Its not working... :/

Comment: @elavarasanlee, PHP_EOL is a constent in all systems?http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: @shin : Ya dats wat they have put... but its not working in my system **dot**.

Comment: @elavarasanlee,Hm.. I can't find what is the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29735/discussion-between-shin-and-elavarasan-lee)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo str_replace("\r\n","", $key);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below Code

```
str_replace(chr(13), "", $key);
```

May this will help you